# Do Heighten Spell and Eldritch Corruption stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, spellcasting, metamagic, stacking

Can Heighten Spell and Eldritch Corruption stack?

Answer (score 5):

## Ask the DM

The benefit of the feat **Eldritch Corruption** says, in part, that

> You can enlarge, extend, heighten, or widen a spell, as though you had the appropriate metamagic feat, without increasing the spell level or, for spontaneous casters, casting time. You can apply any number of these metamagic effects to a spell in this way; if you choose heighten, then that spell’s level is heightened by up to two levels. (*Heroes of Horror* 123)

So while the Eldritch Corruption feat's benefit is *as though* you had used the appropriate metamagic feats, you haven't *actually* used the appropriate metamagic feats. This sort of language is used throughout *D&D 3.5*, and the game never definitively states that when something is *just like* something else then it *actually is* that something else. So whether you can combine *something* and *something else* that's just like *something* only called a different name is up in the air, which is dumb and frustrating and why you'll have to ask the DM.

## This DM would allow it

Given the restrictions on the feat's acquisition from the feat's type (it's a tainted feat) *and* its prerequisites (taking the feat requires the creature be (at least? only?) moderately depraved, the effects of which are difficult to game—but the depravity treacherous is, at least, hilarious), increasing a spell by 2 levels by dealing an ally 2 points of Constitution damage seems reasonable even if the feat [Heighten Spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#heightenSpell) has already been applied to the spell.

Comment: Note I am trying to use this with Extra Spell Slot to get spells above my level. :)